# Ejecutar codigo php en navegador con Visual Studio code en ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, vscode

Buenas estoy intentando ejecutar mis archivos .php desde visual studio code ya que quiero unificar html, javascript y php en visual studio code y he visto que necesito configurar una archivo tasks.json (algo asi como esto: https://www.webucator.com/blog/2016/06/launch-files-browser-visual-studio-code/) y claro el problema es que estoy en ubuntu y no encuentra la aplicación en este caso de firefox para poder incluir la dirección en este archivo (seria para abrir ese codigo en navegador)

Answer (score 3):

La ruta a un ejecutable puedes obtenerla usando `which`.

```
$> which firefox

/usr/bin/firefox


$> which google-chrome

/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

A veces esos ejecutables son symlinks. Puedes ver el ejecutable real usando expansión de parámetros:

```
$> realpath $(which firefox)

/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

Pero en general no hay problemas para invocar al symlink (en general... te estoy mirando a ti, PM2)

**Comentario al margen:**

Probablemente Visual Studio abrirá el browser apuntando al servidor de desarrollo de PHP, que escucha en el puerto 8000 y no tendrá reglas de reescritura ni urls bonitas (a menos que hagas un seudo router en PHP que no es difícil pero tampoco eficiente). Puede que no sea tan mágico como esperas. Yo siempre termino instalando nginx y php-fpm en mi máquina de desarrollo. Además es sano que el ambiente local sea un espejo a escala de lo que haya en producción.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque nunca he trabajado con Visual studio en ubuntu pero he trabajado con otros IDE como eclipse o phpstorm estos programas dentro de los settings o preferences normalmente suelen mostrarte los programas disponibles para ejecutar las aplicaciones cuando le des al RUN (servidor, navegador, versión de php etc). Ya te digo nunca he usado visual studio en ubuntu pero supongo que debería ser como en otros IDE y no solamente con el fichero json.